# Autofilling answers with conditional logic?

Tags: conditional-statements, autofill, calculated-field, redcap

I have a 1x3 table that contains embedded fields. Here is the row below:

```
Row 1: Baseline | 3 Months | 6 Months
```

Each of these options (Baseline, 3 Months, 6 Months), are a field type of Multiple Choice - Drop Down List (single answer), and contain the answers of:

```
1, Yes, Completed
2, No, Withdrawn
3, No, Missing
```

I want to know if there's a way to auto-fill the following answers based on the answer I choose from Baseline. For example, if I choose option 2 (No, Withdrawn) for Baseline, could it also auto-fill "No, Withdrawn" for fields 3 Months and 6 Months?

I'm having trouble using Calculated Fields (first time using) and Conditional Logic Statements (I think this is what I'm supposed to be using, but I continue to get syntax errors). I understand Branching Logic and thought it would work, but that's only to "Show the field ONLY if..." rather than auto-fill answers, unfortunately.

I tried statements such as:

`IF[(baseline) = 2] then[(3Months = 2) and (6Months = 2)]`, but it didn't work. I couldn't find any specific examples online to input more advanced conditional statements.

Please let me know if I should be looking at something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can't (without injecting some JavaScript) automatically select a choice based on the selected choice from another field on the same form. But perhaps it would help to go back through your requirements to see if there's a better, more REDCappy way to do what you want.

I assume you want to mark events as completed, either because the participant has successfully completed the data collection for that event, or they have withdrawn, or otherwise they were not contactable (missing?) and you want to mark their event as, well, 'incomplete' and leave it at that.

Rather than having a form that allows you to set the status for every event, I'd suggest having a field (maybe on its own form and there might be other data associated with it that also belongs on the same form, like `[completed_date]`) that is designated on every event. If you consider this field to be collecting the status of the current event only, then you can query that information across multiple events.

For your specific example, you could use a calculated field to store the withdrawal information if any of the event-specific status fields have value 2. So, outside of your three events, you could have an 'admin' event with an 'admin' form, and a 'withdrawn' field with this calculation equation:

```
if([baseline_arm_1][event_status] = '2' or [3_month_arm_1][event_status] = '2' or [6_month_arm_1][event_status] = '2', 1, 0)
```

Then, if any of the [event_status] fields record 2, 'No, withdrawn', then this field in the admin form will be set to 1. Then you have a more global value for 'withdrawn' which you can access using `[admin_arm_1][withdrawn]`, to use for limiting ASIs and Alerts (by including logic `… AND [admin_arm_1][withdrawn] != '1'`) or for only displaying records that are still active in the project (by creating a custom record status dashboard with a filter `[admin_arm_1][withdrawn] != '1'`).

Please feel free to give more information about your specific use case.